# How to create c# app.config file if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, config

For example, user deleted the `app.exe.config` file by mistake. So the next time he opens the program, it shows an error. I tried creating the file but for that to work, user needs to reopen the program. I think there is an initializing issue. How can I do it manually?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: What is the problem when you create the file manually?

Comment: Build your application in `Release` mode and you should get the `YourApp.exe.config` in your `bin\Release` directory - copy that and send it to your user....

Comment: After creating, if the user tries to open settings menu, there goes a null reference exception. That's why I think it's about initializing.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to make program handle it itself. Creating or sending are both solutions but isn't there a one-step way?

Comment: You could have your app check for the file's existence **before** loading any data from it - and if it's missing, create a default `.config` file in the right place

Answer (score 5):

My opinion to that: If the user has delete the App.Exe.Config file (from the application path ,which is read only to normal users!), he can only do that with adminstrator privileges. A administrator should know what he is doing, so the punishment is "reinstall the application".

Comment: Lousy solution, reinstall a complete application only because a (probably) small config file is missing. A more elegant solution is to recreate a default config file if it is missing...

Comment: @PoweRoy: Not at all. A App.Config file belongs to the program. Like e.g. manifest or assemblies (business layer, data layer, etc.) I don't think that "self-reparing" software is possible.

Comment: assemblies etc are needed to function. A config file imho is only there for configurational purposes (language, connection string). Without a config file a application should still be usable.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Once again, not at all. You are correct, the assemblies contains the functionality. The config file contains the adaption of the program to the situation it is installed in. Nothing else should be configured in it. The rest is data or settings and belongs to different places!

Answer (score 1):

You can check for it's existance like thiss:

```
if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someproperty"]));
```

If not exists you can create it, and I think it would be tedious to create it programmatically check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Answer (score -4):

you can try delete the app.config and then create the same one, recompile the project again.